# Gson Type Adapter is not thread safe?

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, gson, thread-safety

Here is my BigDecimal adapter (to serialize the amount based on configuration):

```java
public class BigDecimalAdapter extends TypeAdapter<BigDecimal> {
    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final BigDecimal value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            out.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        final var scale = ThreadLocalContextUtil.getFractionalDigits();
        if (scale != null) {
            final var newVal = value.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
            out.value(newVal);
        } else {
            out.jsonValue(value.toPlainString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        final var s = in.nextString();
        try {
            return new BigDecimal(s);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new JsonSyntaxException("Failed parsing '" + s + "' as BigDecimal; at path " + in.getPreviousPath(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

In here, `final var scale = ThreadLocalContextUtil.getFractionalDigits();` is picking the value from ThreadLocal.

The issue is when I run test with multithread, it seems the other API that has scale=null also serialized as 0.0, This is not expected.

The API that has no scale value (scale = null) should keep the original way.

Comment: Your adapter code looks thread-safe to me; could you please share your `ThreadLocalContextUtil` code as well? But note that "0.0" is apparently also a valid return value for `toPlainString()`, for example: `new BigDecimal("0.0").toPlainString()` (tested with JDK 17)

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue. I have to clear the value of ThreadLocalContextUtil and the end of request so it will always has default value as null.